# Swapy could not be used to access swing properties of swing based java application.How to access swing properties of a java application

Tags: python, swing, ui-automation, pywinauto

I am using swapy(desktop automation tool which uses pywinauto python package) to automate desktop UI activities, but swapy does not recognize the properties of a swing based java application, but it can recognize the properties of other applications like notepad windows media player etc..

can anybody please the reason for this problem

and
can I use swing explorer for this swing based application of which I don not have code, just the application

If i cant use it, please give me a way/solution to access the properties of swing based java application.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pywinauto uses standard windows API calls. Unfortunately many UI libraries (like Swing/QT/GTK) do not respond in a typical way to the API calls used - so unfortunately pywinauto usually cannot get the control information. (I am the Author of pywinauto).

I can't give you a way to access the properties of the Swing controls.